# How do you parse JSON Data in Arduino

Tags: c, json, arduino, text-parsing, arduino-yun

I want to parse JSON data from a File in Arduino, how can I do this, I am using Arduino Yun.

One other way I was wondering was to run shell script to take unnecessary data out of the file and leave the data that was necessary for parsing with comma separated but some how when I run this command : 
Serial.println(p.runShellCommand("more /mnt/sda1/json.txt |grep -o \"[^ ]*$ " ));
I don't seem to get output at the serial Monitor and i'm not able to save the content in a variable.
Please help out with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

C doesn't have built in JSON parsing capability. Your options are to use something like [Jsmn](http://zserge.com/jsmn.html), or [aJson](https://github.com/interactive-matter/aJson) (arduino JSON) or have your data provider give it to you in a different format if possible.